# Focus is Getting Lost on adapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-tv

In my Android TV app, the action button in the ActionsRow loses focus on

```
adapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(0, 1);
```

call. I am using:

```
View focusedView = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
```

to get the focused view, but cannot set the focus back on after *notifyArrayItemRangeChanged*. The button with the focus before *notifyArrayItemRangeChanged* loses focus, and I can't make that button *requestFocus* in (or after) *onBindViewHolder* of the *ActionPresenter* or in *onBindRowViewHolder* of *ActionsRowPresenter*... The focus is set to the first button every time after *notifyArrayItemRangeChanged*.

Any ideas how to retain focus or how to set it back to the original view?

**ActionPresenter:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder called, item:" + item.toString());
    Action action = (Action) item;
    ActionViewHolder vh = (ActionViewHolder) viewHolder;
    vh.mAction = action;
    vh.mButton.setText(action.getLabel1());
    vh.mButton.setTag(action.getId());

    vh.mButton.requestFocus();
}
```

**ActionsRowPresenter:**

```
protected void onBindRowViewHolder(ActionsRowPresenter.ViewHolder holder, Object item) {
    super.onBindRowViewHolder(holder, item);
    Log.i(TAG, "onBindRowViewHolder called");

    ViewHolder vh = holder;
    ActionsRow row = (ActionsRow) vh.getRow();

    ArrayObjectAdapter aoa = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mActionPresenter);
    aoa.addAll(0, (Collection)row.getActions());
    vh.bind(aoa);
}
```

**NowPlayingChannelRowPresenter:**

```
public NowPlayingChannelRowPresenter(Channel c) {
    setHeaderPresenter(null);
    setSelectEffectEnabled(false);

    mSelectedChannel = c;

    npcdrPresenter = new NowPlayingChannelDetailsRowPresenter(new DetailsDescriptionPresenter());
    actionsRowPresenter = new ActionsRowPresenter();

    ClassPresenterSelector ps = new ClassPresenterSelector();

    ps.addClassPresenter(NowPlayingChannelDetailsRow.class, npcdrPresenter);
    ps.addClassPresenter(ActionsRow.class, actionsRowPresenter);

    npcdRow = new NowPlayingChannelDetailsRow(mSelectedChannel);

    actionsRow = new ActionsRow(mSelectedChannel);

    actionsRow.addAction(new Action(ACTION_START_STOP, "Stop"));
    actionsRow.addAction(new Action(ACTION_ADD_REMOVE_FAVORITE, "Add to Favorites"));

}


@Override
protected RowPresenter.ViewHolder createRowViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.now_playing_channel_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    vh.mNpcdVh = (NowPlayingChannelDetailsRowPresenter.ViewHolder) npcdrPresenter.onCreateViewHolder(vh.llNpcd);
    vh.llNpcd.addView(vh.mNpcdVh.view);

    vh.mActionsVh = (ActionsRowPresenter.ViewHolder) actionsRowPresenter.onCreateViewHolder(vh.llActions);
    vh.llActions.addView(vh.mActionsVh.view);

    return vh;
}


@Override
protected void onBindRowViewHolder(RowPresenter.ViewHolder holder, Object item) {
    super.onBindRowViewHolder(holder, item);

    ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) holder;
    npcdrPresenter.onBindRowViewHolder(vh.mNpcdVh, npcdRow);
    actionsRowPresenter.onBindRowViewHolder(vh.mActionsVh, actionsRow);

}
```

**Edit 1:** There's no ListView, I am using an ArrayObjectAdapter instance with custom presenters

**Edit 2:** I attached the layout view (Hiearchy View).

[image]

Comment: what view you are using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get called only for the item that needs to be focussed

> vh.mButton.requestFocus();

If you notify the adapter just for the first item in the ActionPresenter, onBindViewHolder will be called just for the first item and it will get the focus.

If it is the second item that needs to be focussed, ActionPresenter's onBindViewHolder should get called for that item and you should request focus  only for the second item and not all items.

Comment: How do I notfiy the adapter just for the first item? Do I have to override a method in ActionsRowPresenter?

Comment: Do you want to focus the first item or the second? What items does the adapter include in adapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(0, 1)?

Comment: The adapter contains the NowPlayingChannelRow, which consists of an NowPlayingChannelDetailsRow and a ActionsRow (see the image). I only want the NowPlayingChannelDetailsRow to be refreshed, and thus calling adapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(0, 1); When it is called, the ActionsRow is rendered again, and the focus is lost

Comment: What happens when you request focus vh.mButton.requestFocus() inside onBindViewHolder of ActionPresenter only when action.getLabel1() equals the label of the view to be focussed?

Answer (score 1):

If your `listview` extends `Activity` then try :

```
listviewName.setSelection(positionOfItem);
```

and if your `listview` extends `ListActivity` then try :

```
getListView().setSelection(positionOfItem);
```

It will be focused on the specific position even after listView is updated.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no listview.